# having a timeout for mobx's when?

Tags: mobx

Is there a clean way for a mobx when() call to fire after a timeout even if the predicate hasn't been true?

I could set an observable after a setTimeout and check that in the predicate, but then I'd have more to clean up.  when has an options parameter but I haven't found the documentation for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [whenWithTimeout](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-utils#whenwithtimeout) from [mobx-utils](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-utils) package

If you are using MobX 4.0.0 or higher you can just pass `timeout` directly to `when` as its option (3rd parameter). It has been mentioned in [the changelog](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400)

Comment: Cool.  Is there a way my onError handler can distinguish timeouts from other errors?

Comment: whenWithTimeout has a nicer signature as I am not assuming any error is a timeout, but unfortunately I get a deprecation warning.  BTW mobx rocks and I appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

pass the optional params as an object...

> when(predicate: () => boolean, effect?: () => void, options?);

```
when(() => true,
 () => { ..do something },
 { timeout: 1000 }
)
```